# How can i use the intersection from AS3 to make a reposition of a Rectangle?

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine, game-physics, flashdevelop, starling-framework

After a detected collision between 2 Rectangles (i used the intersects method), i wish to reposition the Rectangle "player".

I'm working with Flash Develop + Starling.

Comment: Please add more information and give us some of your current code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use BitmapData intersection, see `hitTest`.

See code here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/hit-test-ignoring-transparent-pixels